# WPF: A button to both open and close a second window on click? (toggle open)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

This is the template:

```
//Button Opens and Closes 'Basic Arithmetic' Window.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 BasicArithmetic = new Window1();
    if (BasicArithmetic.IsActive == false)
    {
        BasicArithmetic.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        BasicArithmetic.Close();
    }    
}
```

This code succesfully opens the window, yet doesn't close the window...

Can you think of a better test for the if statement?

Please Help : ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@daniel.shih** i was able to figure it out, here is the working code:

```
Window1 BasicArithmetic = new Window1();

//Button Opens and Closes Basic Arithmetic Window
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BasicArithmetic.IsVisible == false)
        {
            BasicArithmetic.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            BasicArithmetic.Hide();
        }            

    }
```

I moved the `Window1` line above the click event as suggested by **@daniel.shih**

I changed the `IsActive` test to `IsVisible`

I changed `.Close()` to `.Hide()`